# What does "Type Error: Can't convert 'int' to str implicitly" mean?

Tags: python

```
def display_positive_indices(strlen):
    print()
    print(' ', end='')
    for i in range(strlen + 1):
        print(i, end='')
        if i != strlen:
            print(' ' * (4 - len(str(i))), end='')
    print()
```

Hi, I'm new to programming. This is my code. The error first points to the main function. Then it points to this function in the main then it points to:
`for i in range(strlen + 1)` and it says `Type Error: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`. Why does it say this? What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: What is `strlen` when you call it? (Also, I assume this is Python 3, not 2, because of the print functions, but it's best to say so explicitly.) Also, please show the actual error output, rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: thats what the error says. word for word is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kavitavijayan/Workspace/Chp6Prob5/stringslicer.py", line 91, in <module>
     main()
  File "/Users/kavitavijayan/Workspace/Chp6Prob5/stringslicer.py", line 73, in main
    display_positive_indices(string)
  File "/Users/kavitavijayan/Workspace/Chp6Prob5/stringslicer.py", line 33, in display_positive_indices
    for i in range(strlen + 1):
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: So since you know the error is in that line, why not try making a minimal test case, breaking it down until the problem goes away. You'll see that `range(strlen + 1)` has the same exception, so next try `strlen + 1`, which again has the same exception, so next try `strlen`, which doesn't… now you know what to ask about ("Why does `strlen + 1` raise this exception?") without making us wade through other code.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you show us the `main` function? I'll bet we find the problem there even faster.

Answer (score 7):

Your function works fine if you call it with an integer, such as:

```
In [499]: display_positive_indices(3)

 0   1   2   3
```

But when you call it with a string, you get this error, and the interpreter tells you more information:

```
In [500]: display_positive_indices('3')

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-500-dd39f751056c> in <module>()
----> 1 display_positive_indices('3')

<ipython-input-495-ac7e32dd0c50> in display_positive_indices(strlen)
      2     print()
      3     print(' ', end='')
----> 4     for i in range(strlen + 1):
      5         print(i, end='')
      6         if i != strlen:

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

The problem is that `strlen + 1`. You're trying to add a `str` to an `int`. You get the exact same error with just this:

```
In [501]: strlen = '3'

In [502]: strlen + 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-502-5a3ed0dba868> in <module>()
----> 1 strlen + 1

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

In Python 3, trying to add something to a `str` starts off by trying to implicitly convert that other thing to a `str`, and, as the error says, you can't do that with an `int`.

Meanwhile, for future reference, here's how to debug an error like this:

To start off with, you know which line in your function has the error. So, keep removing stuff until the error goes away. First:

```
def display_positive_indices(strlen):
    for i in range(strlen + 1):
        pass
```

Same error. So:

```
def display_positive_indices(strlen):
    range(strlen + 1)
```

And again:

```
def display_positive_indices(strlen):
    strlen + 1
```

And:

```
def display_positive_indices(strlen):
    strlen
```

OK, that last one succeeded, so the problem was in `strlen + 1`. Everything else is irrelevant. So, you've narrowed down what you have to figure out, ask about, and/or understand.

Finally, if you want us to figure out what's wrong with the `main` function, and why it's passing a `str` rather than the `int` you expected, you'll have to show us that function. (Of the top of my head, my first guess is that you're using `input` to get a length from the user, and not converting it, possibly because you read the Python 2 docs on `input` instead of the Python 3 docs. But I'd give that guess a 20% chance of being right at best.)

Comment: Thanks for responding! But strlen is an integer it is the length of a string

Comment: @KavitaVijayan: that seems unlikely.  After the first `print()`, add `print(type(strlen), repr(strlen))`.

Comment: @pst: No, you were right for Py3, but not for Py2. Py3's `str.__add__` method tries an implicit (C-API) conversion to `str` before raising, and that conversion raises exactly this error.

Comment: so after the print() i should add the
print(type(strlen), repr(strlen)) ??

Comment: @pst: You shouldn't have deleted your comment; I tried to upvote it and got an error. (Apparently SO can't add None+1 any better than Python can.:))

Comment: @KavitaVijayan: sure.  That should convince you that `strlen` is a string and not an integer, IOW that this answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you require an integer you can coerce it to the type you would like, and if it cannot be converted you will get a TypeError or ValueError:

```
...
strlen = int(strlen)
for i in range(strlen + 1):
    ...
```